# Laravel, links() pagination The GET method is not supported

Tags: laravel

When I process a post request for search, I get all result with pagination,
when try to navigate to the second page http://localhost/project/admin/search?page=2

** The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

the links() function use GET to navigate in pages, how i can resolve ?

route :

`Route::post('search',['as' => 'cat.search','uses' =>'CatController@search']);`

function :

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
       
        $search = $request->get('search');
        if($search != ''){
            $cat =  Tombe::where('name','like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orwhere('description','like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->paginate(15);
            if(count($cat)>0){
                return view('admin.cat.search', compact('cat'));
            }else{
                return back()->with('error','No results Found');
            }
        }else{
            return back()->with('error','Enter Search Name');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pagination is usually a `GET` request, i.e. `http://localhost/project/admin/search?page=2`, when navigating directly to that URL, triggers a `GET`. Either change your code to `Route::get()`, or don't use Pagination, or find a way to get Pagination to work as a `POST` request (not something I've ever tried to do, so no idea how you'd do that)

Comment: in my case the user search with keyword il large data (POST) and use pagination to navigate in result, ?page=2 (GET). need to add route?

Comment: If you really need to use POST, you'd need to create your own pagination view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Lewis pointed out, the paginator by default works with GET requests. In order to make it use POST requests, you'd need to provide a custom view to the Paginator's `links()` method replacing every `<a>` tag with a `<form>`.

For example, the default view is visible in [the github repo](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/default.blade.php) along with [some others that use bootstrap or tailwind.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/10.x/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views)

If you are not using laravel 10, simply change the branch. [Here is the folder for laravel 5.5 for example](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.5/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views)

Here's what the default pagination for laravel 10 would look like if you make it use `POST` requests instead.

`resources/views/pagination/using-post.blade.php`

```xml
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @else
                <li>
                    {{-- <a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</a> --}}
                    <form action="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
            @endif

            {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
            @foreach ($elements as $element)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                @if (is_string($element))
                    <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span>{{ $element }}</span></li>
                @endif

                {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                @if (is_array($element))
                    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                            <li class="active" aria-current="page"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                        @else
                            {{-- <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li> --}}
                            <form action="{{ $url }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <button type="submit">{{ $page }}</button>
                            </form>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach

            {{-- Next Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li>
                    {{-- <a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</a> --}}
                    <form action="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </nav>
@endif
```

And then you'd need to pass this custom pagination view of yours to the paginator when you use the `links()` method.

```xml
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>
 
{{ $users->links('pagination.using-post') }}
```